# EditText in loop problem

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-edittext

In my code when I create the EditText boxes I set them to accept numbers only, but this only applies to the first column of the EditText boxes.  The following columns then won't accept anything to be entered in them.  What is causing this?

My code:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < MatrixMultiply.h1; i++){
       columnEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();
       TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
       TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
       EditText column;
       for(int j = 0; j < MatrixMultiply.w1; j++){
           column = new EditText(this);
           column.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
           column.setId(i);
           row.addView(column);
           columnEditTexts.add(column);
       }
       table.addView(row);
       arrayOfEditTexts.add(columnEditTexts);
   }
```

Comment: Side note.. why are you creating an EditText when you're not using it? (The one before the second `for` loop)

Comment: Also, why do you re-lookup `table` in your inner loop? You already got it once above there. It's not going to change.

Comment: I wonder if you take away `column.setId(i)` would work or not. You are setting the same ID on every edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering if it's okay that you're setting every column in a row to have the same id.

Comment: i*j will still have collisions. You'll need to do `i * MatrixMultiply.w1 + j`.